# Prevent input event from firing when changing textarea programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `textarea` that can be edited by the user. I occasionally update the text programmatically by changing the element's `value` property. I need an event that triggers when the user changes the text, but not when the program changes it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use keyup as the event trigger which will allow the user activity to trigger the function but not if you do it programmatically

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('textArea_id'), 'keyup', function(event) {
//function goes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to add that `ondragend` is necessary to catch changes made by dragging text.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the 'input' event to the textbox. This would fire every time the input changes, so when you paste something (even with right click), delete and type anything.

```
$('.bind').on('input', function() {
    // do something
});
```

If you use the change handler, this will only fire after the user deselects the input box.

There is an example of both here: https://jsfiddle.net/nanilab/qxv4n824/

Comment: sorry @arglab - but jQuery wasn't tagged in the OP's  question. I would have suggested a jQ version of my answer if it had been :))

Comment: @gavgrif Yes, I didn't read the tags. It's a good answer anyway, it isn't? :)